# Ember.Select - How to fill in these values?

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember.js in my rails app, and have gotten a pretty good grip on things so far.  However, I'm trying to put in a birthday dropdown, using the Ember.Select statement.  I'm wondering what the best way & where to add in values to this select would be?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say birthday dropdown, do you mean a calendar like [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: After visiting the link, I just realized that Datepicker has an option to select month and years from the dropdown.  That's exactly what I need, now I just need to get it integrated with ember. :)

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ztUKv/) go to the 'appointment' link. I have this sort of "on the makes" cause I was testing it the other day. It's not fully functional, but you can extend that code

Comment: I'm actually having too much trouble integrating datepicker, and am on kind of a timecrunch, so I'm going back to just the simple Select dropdowns.  However I did find this: stackoverflow.com/questions/8911206/select-dropdown-with-ember which is helping me a bit.  If I get it all figured out to work with birthdays, I'll post an answer to my original question.  Thanks for the help though MilkyWay, I'm sure I'll implement datepicker in the future!

Comment: I have made this in an application http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/czS8R/ I expect this help